# making a direction go until hitting something without being interrupted by other inputs

Tags: c++, game-development

I'm making a simple game in my terminal where once you choose a direction to go in it keeps going that direction no matter what you do until it hits a wall, then you can choose another direction. I have made collision detection but I can still go in any direction without hitting a wall first. What should I try? this is just the movement code btw

```
int main() {
if (_kbhit())
{
    switch (_getch())
    {
    case 'w':
        dir = UP;
        break;
    case 's':
        dir = DOWN;
        break;
    case 'a':
        dir = LEFT;
        break;
    case 'd':
        dir = RIGHT;
        break;
    }
}
switch (dir)
{
case LEFT:
    x--;
    break;
case RIGHT:
    x++;
    break;
case UP:
    y--;
    break;
case DOWN:
    y++;
}
//ex for collision detection:
if (x == blockx && y == blocky && dir == LEFT)
    x + 1;
```

}

Comment: You haven't written the "keep going until you hit a wall" part.

Comment: Without any loops, this code looks like it will exit after a single step.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry this is my code for my game but I wrote it again on this to just focus on this part but it does have a loop that continues the game

Comment: I cannot figure out the keep going until you hit a wall part i have tried loops and if statements but none of them have worked and that is what i am trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

As for me in this situation I would use while loop for going to whatever direction and after each step I would check for collision, once I collide to a wall I will break the loop and the switch, too. I think the idea should be like this at least, but I am not sure about the code, cause I didn't understand the task clearly.

```
switch (dir)
{
case LEFT:
    while (1) {
        x--;
        //ex for collision detection:
        if (x == blockx && y == blocky && dir == LEFT) {
            x + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
case RIGHT:
    while (1) {
        x++;
        //ex for collision detection:
        if (x == blockx && y == blocky && dir == LEFT) {
            x + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
case UP:
    while (1) {
        y--;
        //ex for collision detection:
        if (x == blockx && y == blocky && dir == LEFT) {
            x + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
case DOWN:
    while (1) {
        y++;
        //ex for collision detection:
        if (x == blockx && y == blocky && dir == LEFT) {
            x + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes the game freeze and this problem with the game freezing has been happening I don't know why and the goal is to make it so once you go in a direction you have to keep going in the direction no matter what you press until you hit a wall which then you could choose another direction

Comment: I think it is because collision detection doesn't work correctly, I mean you should correct them, I don't know how and where walls are located. So therefore I just copy pasted your lines of code for detecting collision.